# Phonegap InAppBrowser Controls iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using Phonegap 2.6 on iOS and when a link opens it uses the fullscreen with no way of going back to the app. Is there a way to trigger some sort of controls to go back to the app? The code I have is below:

```
 function shareonfb()
    {
        photoid = sessionStorage.PhotoId;
        filename = sessionStorage.PhotoFilename;

        postUrl  = "http://site.com/sharedimage.php?photoid="+photoid;

        imageUrl = "http://site.com/images/"+filename;

        var sSiteUrl="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&u="+postUrl; 

        var ref = window.open(sSiteUrl, '_self', 'location=yes', 'presntationstyle=pagesheet');


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing `_self` to `_blank`

So:

```
var ref = window.open(sSiteUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```